# Could anyone give me a brief intro about How webrtc work

Tags: webrtc

All:

I read some intro posts about WebRTC, feel exciting but still a lot of confuse.

Some posts talks the WEBRTC need a server to relay while others say it only need client side support.

I wonder if anyone can give me a brief talk about how webRTC work with a simple example(like how to setup a P2P video meeting)

THanks

Comment: With absolutely zero knowledge about webRTC, I mean this as an honest (and not at all rhetorical) question: isn't this question too broad for SO?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thanks for comment. Well, it could be, could you narrow it?

Comment: As I said, I know nothing about WebRTC. What's even worse, I'm new to SO:) I tried looking at the help, but I haven't found a decisive point (I was looking through the help pages: [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]). Anyway, preferred questions usually have a specific point with which the asker is stuck or confused. Questions like yours likely need an answer saying "well you can read it here: [link]".

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials and example projects out there spanning many different situations. This question, as it is(and I don't think it could be corrected) is off topic for SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two articles that describe pretty everything you need to start using WebRTC:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/

Comment: Thanks. BTW, do you have any JS testing experience, I am total newbie to testing, right now, my boss want me to add test to workflow, do you know generally what( this is most important, I can figure out how to do that once I know what should be tested generally) should I test and how to do that?

Comment: Sorry, @Kuan, I'm an Android programmer, and barely know JS.